# Difficulty with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have started using scala sbt pretty recently. One thing which I find very difficult with SBT is to find the right dependency signature.

for example, I am reading a blog which was written in 2014 and it says add the following libraryDependencies

```
"net.liftweb" %% "lift-son" % "2.5+"
"org.apache.httpcomponents" %% "httpclient" % "4.5"
```

Now this may or may not be valid for my environment. since I have installed a more recent version of scala and sbt.

Now when I try to search with google, I find even more stale resources which may not refer to the current environment.

I even look at the maven repository

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.liftweb

and now I see a bunch of versions.

So my question is how to determine which is the right lift-json for me? I see lot of people doing this by trial and error and copy and paste.

So with trial and error I realized that for lift-json I should use

```
"net.liftweb" %% "lift-son" % "2.5+"
```

What rationale can I use to select the right library for my environment.
The apache httpclient still gives me error.

Sorry if this is too basic. like I said, I am new to SBT. but it seems there is no logical way for me to author this file. its just copy, paste, and then trial and error.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Just pick the version that you want t use

Comment: I want to use apache http client and am ready to use any version which works. I tried the latest version 4.5 but that gave an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%%` in the dependency automatically appends a `_2.XX` scala version to your artifact id. It makes scala dependencies easier to manage, but you can't use it with java dependencies like apache httpcomponents. Instead just use `%`:

```
"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5"
```